# How to make a horizontal pyramid shape triangle

Tags: java

How to make this type of triangle through java.
click to see the picture:

[image]

this is my code for now:

```
    char a,b,c;

     for (a=1;a<=5;a+=1){
       for (b=0;b<b-a;b--)
         System.out.print(' ');
     for (c=0; c<a; c++){

     System.out.print("* ");
    }
     System.out.println("");
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: You can't just show us a picture and expect someone to write the code for you, you need to show some evidence of trying it on your own. Please try the problem and come back with a proper question

Comment: "How to make this type of triangle through Java?" – You do it by writing a Java program which does what you want. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if ((i < 4 && j >= i + 1 && j < 6 - i) || (i > 3 && j < i && j >= 7 - i)) {
                System.out.print("  ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

In the if-statement are two cases, one for the upper part, one for the lower part.

Comment: Can you explain more at the part if?